# Can you use both role mentions and member mentions in one argument?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently trying to make a discord bot with the ability to remind users of something with a mention. I would like to have the bot be able to remind either an individual user, or an entire role. Would there be any way of doing this?

```py
@client.command()
async def remind(ctx, user:discord.Member or discord.Role=None):
    if user == None:
        print("No Input")
    else:
        print(f"Input: {user.name}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `Union[discord.Member, discord.Role]`. Currently, `remind`'s `user`'s annotation is only `discord.Member` because of [how Python's or operator short-circuits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).
2. Use `if user is None:` over `if user == None`.

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.
> https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations
> 3. You'd just need to use `print(f"Input: {user.mention}")`. This works for both [roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.mention) and [users](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.mention).

Thus, we have:

```
    @client.command()
    async def remind(ctx, user: Union[discord.Member, discord.Role] = None):
        if user is None:
            print("No Input")
        else:
            print(f"Input: {user.mention}")
```

Because role instances and user instances have fields `mention`, I suggest renaming `user` to something else. The name implies that it only should be a user, not possibly a role.

Also, note that printing will not actually send a message through Discord.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is exactly what I needed. And yeah, the prints were just for testing at the moment.

Comment: Glad I could help out! I forgot to mention that in [Python 3.10](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/), you can use `user: discord.Member | discord.Role = None`. Right now, we're stuck with using `typing.Union`.